# How to use Split() on elements of an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, dynamic

I'm receiving an input as an array of strings

```
Input[0]:1
2
3
Input[1]:a
b
c
Input[2]:x
y
z
...
```

I am looking to use the split function on each of those elements through a loop so I can isolate them. I don't mind if it's done by creating a group of arrays (Array0[1,2,3]; Array1[a,b,c];...) or by creating a multidimensional array, whichever is best, but I'm struggling with how to create those in a loop.

**EDIT:** I can get it working as expected with this same setup with a single input that splits into an array (e.g. $InputArr = $InputArr.Split("`n")), but as soon as I try it with a 2D array, it doesn't split properly

Current Code:

```
Function Read-example {
    [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [string[]]
            $InputArr
        )


    begin{
    }

    process {

        $InputArr[0] = $InputArr[0].Split("`n")
        Write-Host "Input 0 0: " $InputArr[0][0]
        Write-Host `n "Input 0 1: " $InputArr[0][1]
        Write-Host `n "Input 0 2: " $InputArr[0][2]

    }
```

My Input is:

```
InputArr[0]: 1a
1b
1c
```

And the output is:

```
 Input 0 0:  1

 Input 0 1:  a

 Input 0 2:
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show you code.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have formatted in the question, it looks like the strings in the array elements are separated by newline characters.

```
$arr = "1`r`n2`r`n3", "a`r`nb`r`nc", "x`r`ny`r`nz"
```

If that is the case, simply loop over the array `$arr` and split each element on that newline:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $arr.count; $i++) {
    $arr[$i] = $arr[$i] -split '\r?\n'
}
```

After this, the original array stores sub arrays:

```
$arr[0].GetType() --> String[]
$arr[0][0]  --> 1
$arr[0][1]  --> 2
$arr[0][2]  --> 3
```

etc.

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply - I was trying the idea in your example and I'm not sure if it is me misunderstanding how the input parameter stores things, but I've stripped out the loop and anything else that might be causing the issue. It works fine with a 1d array, but as soon as I try with 2d it doesn't split properly. I've edited the post to include my code